# Cannot use a derived table in WHERE subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why can't I use D in the WHERE subquery?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Orders AS D
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM D) = 11;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT qty 
  FROM dbo.Orders) AS D
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(D.qty) FROM D) = 11;`      I try to count the row numbers of the qty in D without using ROW_NUMBERS

Comment: Can you say that in English?

Comment: Are you trying to select everything from `dbo.Orders` only if `dbo.Orders` has exactly 11 rows?

Comment: I get a derived table after the `FROM` clause using an alias like `D` and try to find if `D` has exactly 11 rows.

Comment: Easy: because `D` is not a table, it's a table alias.

Comment: It works like `SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders AS D WHERE D.id=1;`. Why can't I take `D` in a subquery after `WHERE` clause? I have no idea and cannot find an answer about this in the books or blogs.

Comment: Please read the [documentation on the FROM clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql). You'll see my statement confirmed there.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not a valid syntax... Even if it was, you'd get no results unless there were exactly 11 rows in your Orders table.

I'm guessing that you're looking for something like the following...

```
WITH 
    cte_OrderCount AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            OrderCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.CustomerID)
        FROM 
            dbo.Orders o
        )
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    cte_OrderCount oc
WHERE 
    oc.OrderCount = 11;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, so I'm guessing. But this returns all rows of the table if it has 11 rows:

```
select * from dbo.Orders where exists(select 1 from dbo.Orders having COUNT(*) = 11)
```

Or maybe you were after something like this:

If you need to "join" with the count table, you could use APPLY. e.g.:

```
select c.*, o.* from 
(select COUNT(*) as cc from dbo.Orders) c outer apply
(select * from dbo.Orders) o 
WHERE c.cc = 11
```

The SELECT COUNT(*) line above will always return 1 row. The "c" derived table is then outer applied with the orders table. Then you can use "c" and "o" in the WHERE clause etc.